# Is there a way to visually clip a layer in QGIS to prevent information from rendering outside the boundary?

Tags: qgis

In ArcGIS you are able to Clip to Shape, meaning you can use a shapefile to visually clip anything outside if it. This option does not physically clip anything, nor make a new shapefile.

For example:

You could add the Google satellite imagery and set the clip to prevent having to wait for information outside a certain shape from rendering.

Is there a way to visually clip as mentioned above in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, none of the available tools will reduce waiting time by preventing loading of data outside the clip. You can only cover things up.